# drupal_http_request with proxy

Tags: http-request

I'm working on proxy based machine where I've configured my proxy settings at settings.php and its working fine.

When I'm trying to access a URL the data is getting displayed perfectly, for instance, https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=California but when I'm doing the same thing at my `devel/php`

```
$maps_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=California';
$maps_json = drupal_http_request($maps_url);
dsm($maps_json);
```

it's returning me this:
[image]

I've confirmed 2 settings in my php.ini:

1. allow_url_fopen
2. allow_url_include

[image]

Where else should I look so that this issue will get fixed?

Comment: It's returning a 400 error, but it's not clear from where... the proxy or from Google? If you look more closely at `data` property of the response and the `headers`, this should help you narrow it down. For example, I don't see the API key (you may have omitted it). That could result in an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this module [cURL HTTP Request](https://www.drupal.org/project/chr) via this [thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/2291641#comment-9935752) and it worked like charm. The issue was with HTTPS hence the [HTTP proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_proxy) module wasn't able to help me on this.